# How can I setup a WebTV platform in IIS/Windows?

Tags: asp.net, iis, flowplayer

I want to create a WebTV site in ASP.NET. At the moment I am thinking of using Flowplayer, serving .flv files. Since it will work with pseudostreaming, IIS will serve various .flv files in a schedule.

Is there a platform/open source package to provide all the clip (and advertisement) scheduling to create the WebTV program? Or do I need to create my own scheduling interface (backend) that will store the .flv schedule in a database, and create e.g. an .aspx that will read the current time and decide which clip to serve?

Or are there any better ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to act like a broadcast channel where all viewers see the same thing at the same time, then you want to use live streaming using flash media server, or some other streaming server that supports live streaming.  I'm not aware of any scheduling packages, but I've never looked for them.

If you want to do more of a video on demand idea like youtube or hulu then you could either build that yourself or look at the many web video publishing platforms, like twistage, etc.

Flowplayer has a bunch of off the shelf ad plugins which could be used, it's just a matter of integrating them yourself.  I'm not aware of any all-in-one packages that do everything you are asking for - you'll have to put together the pieces yourself.